# Calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and Me

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

I am working on a custom list inside a SharePoint online site collection. and i have a custom column named "Last Update" of type DateTime, and i want to create a calculated column to show the differences between today and the "Last Update" site column.

So i created a new site column of type Calculated column, with the following formula:-

[image]

and it worked well, but when i tried to add this column inside our list, i got this error:-

[image]

any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below formula to calculate the difference between **Today** and **Last Update** Date column.

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Last Update]),"",(TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy")-[Last Update]))
```

and set `The data type returned from this formula to : Number` in order to get difference in **Number of days** between two dates.

Comment: your formula worked well if the [Last Update] contain a value, while if the [Last Update] is empty the formula will return `44,055`.. can i fix this? to force the formula to return null if the [Last Update] is null?

Comment: @SharePointTestDev , updated the formula to check if Last update is blank, then it will return blank. Kindly check.

Answer (score 2):

We simply cannot use [Today] or [Me] in calculated columns. Use formulas like

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy")) - DATEVALUE(TEXT([Created],"mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

or `=TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy")-[Created]` will be workarounds you can use. And remember if you use DateValue function, you need to set the `The data type returned from this formula is:` to be date.

Comment: your formula worked well if the [Last Update] contain a value, while if the [Last Update] is empty the formula will return `44,055`.. can i fix this? to force the formula to return null if the [Last Update] is null?